# Trouble with PHP Post Variable

Tags: php, html, css, http-post, web-development-server

It is hard to explain but I have been having some issues with the Post variable in PHP. What the problem is is that I have been on Repl.it making a dummy website for some practice with PHP as I am a complete beginner, so I have been trying to a contact form. 
This is the PHP code as the filename "contact-form-handler.php":

```
<?php

  $name = $_Post["name"];   $visitor_email = $_Post["email"];   $message = $POST['message'];


  $email_from = "19braja@rgshw.com";

  $email_subject = "New Form Submission For BXRSTUDIOS";

  $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n ".
                  "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                    "User Message $message.\n";


  $to = "19braja@rgshw.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  $headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

  header("Location: contact.html");


?>
```

This is the HTML code with the filename as "contact.html":

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="contact-title">
    <h1> Want To Contact Us?</h1>
    <h2> We are always here to help</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-form">
    <form id ="contact=form" method="post" action="contact-form-handler.php">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required><br>
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required><br>

          <textarea name="message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message to BXRSTUDIOS" row="4" required></textarea><br>
          <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SUBMIT MESSAGE">
          <p class="back">Not what you needed?<a href="index.php"> Go Back</a>
            </p>
    </form>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why the Post variable isn't working? Here is what is on the console:

```
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _Post in /home/runner/BXRSTUDIOS1/contact-form-handler.php on line 3
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _Post in /home/runner/BXRSTUDIOS1/contact-form-handler.php on line 4
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: POST in /home/runner/BXRSTUDIOS1/contact-form-handler.php on line 5
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] 172.18.0.1:60886 [302]: /contact-form-handler.php
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] 172.18.0.1:60892 [200]: /contact.html
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] 172.18.0.1:60898 [200]: /contact.css
[Thu Apr 16 18:28:08 2020] 172.18.0.1:60906 [200]: /back.jpg
```

Comment: Did you tried $_POST instead of $_Post and $POST? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

The $_Post var is not valid, $_POST is a reserved system variable, and it must be all in caps.

So your code should be:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];   $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];   $message = $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: Don't post answers to trivial typo/spelling errors. They should just be closed with comments.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo but now the console is showing sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found